# Activiti BPMN : how to find future tasks from current task

Tags: java, java-8, activiti

I'm working on integrating **Activiti** BPMN with my Java WebApp. I have successfully defined the flow and executed it as per my requirement, although I'm stuck in a problem that requires me to find all the future task possibilities that can happen from the currently executing task.

Suppose in my XML, I have a workflow with 4 tasks like Task A and then an exclusive gateway and then 3 more tasks going from it. My current executing task is task A and now **I would like to know the possibilities of future tasks** (which are those 3 tasks after gateway). Is this possible anyhow?

I'm stuck here and wasn't able to find any solution to this. I would appreciate it if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Activiti User Guide](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_advanced). The jobs related to tasks for a process are created at certain points and all of them are not created at the same time. The actual point of creating a job would vary. Therefore querying the ACT_RU_JOB table may not be fruitful. Once way to get the tasks would be to process the BPMN attached to the process definition. The BPMN definition can be retrieved from Activiti API or REST API ([resources in a deployment](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_list_resources_in_a_deployment)). Once the BPMN XML is obtained, it is a matter of finding the task element (user task, service task etc.) and follow the sequence flows to determine which tasks come in which order. As an example, refer the below excerpt from a BPMN:

```
<serviceTask id="servicetask1" 
             name="Process Init" 
             activiti:async="true" 
             activiti:class="ProcessInitDelegate"></serviceTask>

<serviceTask id="servicetask2" 
             name="Download Installed SW List" 
             activiti:async="true"
             activiti:class="EWSAttachmentDownloaderDelegate"></serviceTask>

 <sequenceFlow id="flow2" 
               sourceRef="servicetask1" 
               targetRef="servicetask2"></sequenceFlow>
```

In the above example, it is quite easy to find the sequence flow(s) that go out from 'serviceTask1' and follow it to 'serviceTask2'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get that through BPMN XML I can parse the tasks and can know which task comes after which, but isn't this approach work for a given BPMN diagram? Every time the diagram changes I have to make changes in code. How can I make this generic that will work for any diagram that uploaded.

Comment: This is a generic approach. Let us say you know the task id immediately after which all tasks you need to list. Then find the task element from the BPMN and then the sequence flows that go out of the task and the targets for the sequence flows will your immediate next tasks. You could write a generic XQuery. Otherwise a simple DOM processing of the BPMN will also do. For XQuery processor, refer to http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.8/using-xquery.html